# how to cut html content in a string in c#

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a HTML content and it's a description and I want to cut it using substring function. But it shows error.

Here is my HTML:

```
<span style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 13px; color: #000000;"><p><span style="font-  family: verdana; font-size: 13px; color: #000000;">There's no need to sacrifice performance with a small system.<br />  <br />  Experience the eco-friendly Small Form Factor (SFF) desktop platform  powered by the 2nd generation Intel&reg; Core&trade; vPro&trade; processor family.<br />  <br />  The EVO DQ67, coupled with the latest Intel&reg; Active Management  Technology (Intel&reg; AMT) 7.0, provides the unprecedented secured and  seamless PC remote management in SFF platform, featuring the latest  SuperSpeed USB 3.0, SATA 6 Gb/s technologies, and triple graphic port  options.<br />  <br />  </span><span style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 13px; color: #000000;">Select from our range of pre configured sytems or tell us what you want and we will build you your own individul    bespoke PC.</span></p>
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to cut it? Cut as in wrap the text to a new line? Or only show a certain amount of characters?

Comment: not a real question. Describe what you want, what's your goal, etc. and please post the error you get, the code you tried, etc. Read the [ask] page for more information.

Comment: i only want to show a certain amount of characters

Answer (score 0):

Really need more details on how you are doing this. Try to escape quotes in your string with the backslash so that *style="font-family:* becomes *style=\"font-family:*.